# Excel: How to assign data to bubble diagram to influence bubble size

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm working on a report in which I want to create a bubble diagram, which represents the ocurrances of genders male and female corresponding to a specific age, but I'm struggling with editing the data view, so it displays the results as I want them.

My data rows look as follows:
[image]

The numbers following the labels "Male" and "Female" represent the number of ocurrances of the specific gender corresponding to the given age in the first row.

What I would like the diagram to look like:
[image]

And this is the current diagram I could create for now, but even after trying to align the data according to how I understand, how diagrams work in excel, I still can't assign the data on the correct axis:

[image]

Is it even possible in excel to create a bubble diagram the way I want to?
Thank you very much for your answers in advance.

- Tobbe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the help of two helper rows, each filled with the same number:

[image]

You then right click on the chart and select `Select Data` and choose `Edit`:

[image]

For the Y value of each series, enter the corresponding helper row:

[image]

Your chart should now look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It worked really well. I sometimes forget to create helper data for creating the diagram and not just for the raw data itself.